# AngularJS onload - Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am playing around with different ways of loading an alert on load with angularJS. I saw this method documented:

http://jsfiddle.net/AQ533/9/

JS

```
$scope.init = function () {
  ($window.mockWindow || $window).alert('Hello');
};
```

HTML

```
<div data-ng-controller="myCtrl" data-ng-init="init()">
<span id="logo">Just a</span><span id="small" >PREVIEW</span>    
</div>
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong with this implementation please?

Comment: Wait, if I'm not mistaken `$scope` only exists inside a controller, whereas your code isn't. In that case it's not so strange `$scope` isn't defined.

Comment: i've posted this link in your previous question' page , have a look:  http://plnkr.co/edit/uO9l7n?p=preview

Comment: @chemiv Yours seems like another implementation, with a lot more code though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must define `myCtrl` in order to have `$scope` available:

```
function myCtrl($scope, $window) {
    $scope.init = function () {
      ($window.mockWindow || $window).alert('Hello');
    };
}
```

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davintryon/4xN5s/2/).

**Edit:**
I had to wrap your fiddle with a `div` that included `ng-app`.  `ng-app` tells angular where the global scope of the application is.  This allows it to compile everything inside and see if it can find any controllers etc.

Also, `$scope` must be passed in to the implementation of controller `myCtrl` with any dependencies afterward (in this case `$window` service).

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but your fiddle still doesn't show the alert on page load, is something else missing?

Comment: @Jimmy yes, sorry about that, I've updated the fiddle.  I had to add `ng-app` and use the built-in way of initializing angular.